# React native: default value for route/screen navigation params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

in my react native app I set screen parameters as:

```
const { chat_id, headerTitle, headerImage, receiver_id, user, adrequest_id, ad_id, ad , name} = useRoute().params;
```

I want to set default values for this parameters, with props I can set default values like this, but this doesn't seem to work with screen params.

```
const {  planId = 0 } = props;
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you need is [initialParams](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/#initial-params)